# Arc length and upper bound

Tags: complex-analysis

> Use $||\int_{\lambda} f(z)dz|| \leq max_{z\ on \lambda}|f(z)| \dot\
>  l(\lambda)$, where $l(\lambda)$ is the arc length, to establish the
>   indicated estimate
>
> a.) If $\lambda$ is the vertical line segment from $z=R(>0)$ to
>   $z=R+2\pi i$, then $$||\int_{\lambda} \frac{e^{3z}}{1+e^z}dz|| \leq
>  \frac{2\pi e^{3R}}{e^R -1}$$
>
> b.) If $\gamma$ is the arc of the circle $|z|=1$ that lies in the
>   first quadrant, then  $$||\int_{\gamma}Log(z)dz|| \leq
>  \frac{\pi^{2}}{4}$$

For a.) I first must find the length of $z=R+2\pi i$which throws me off because of the $R$. Then what I did was seek an upper bound for the function inside the integration. Thus, $|e^{3z}|=|e^{3(x+iy)}|=?$ so I must find $|z|$ which I do not know how to do because of the $R$.

For b.) I use used the same process as I did a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a), the arc-length is simple $2\pi$. Moreover, the maximum of the function inside the integrand is just $e^{3R}/{e^R-1}$. (Notice that $|e^z|$ is always $|e^{3R}|$ for $z$ on the arc indicated.)
For (b), the arc is $\pi/4$, while the masimum of the integrand is $\pi/2$, hence the result. (Quite unsure of the answer, but the principle is the same.)
Inform me of any errors, thanks.

> Edit: 
>   The arc in (a) is a straght line of the form $|$. Since, on this arc, $z$ will have the same real part, and as the absolute valkue of $e^z$ does not depend upon the imaginary part of $z$, $|e^z|$ is a constant on the arc. Hence the estimate in (a).
>   The arc in (b) is a fourth of the unit circle. So its length is $\frac{1}{4}\pi\cdot1^2$. Since $log(z)$ takes $e^{i\theta}$ to $i\theta$, $|logz|$on the given arc has maximum value=$\pi/2$, as, on that arc, $z$ is of the form $e^{i\theta}$, for $\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi/2$. Feel free to ask more, if this is still ambiguous.

Comment: Hm, how did you get those answers?

Comment: Where you cannot understand, I can try to shed some light upon. So, where am I not clear enough?

Comment: How did you get both the arc lengths? Also, why would $e^{3R}/{e^R-1}$ be the maximus?

Comment: How about the edited version now?

Comment: Much better, thanks a lot !